# Having problems with scrolling down on page

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I've been creating a website for a school project. I have some information at the bottom of the page but when i open the page up and test it, i can not scroll down to see this information. I have tried overflow:scroll on my page but it still does not see to be working. I was wondering if anyone could help with this issue?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Homepage</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">

<div class="Head">
<div class="Head-box" style="background-color:#BDBDBD;">
</div>


<div onClick="window.location = 'Homepage.html';" class="Home">Home</div>

<div onClick="window.location = 'Activities.html';" class="Activities">Activities</div>

<div onClick="window.location = 'Cafe.html';" class="Cafe">Cafe</div>

<div onClick="window.location = 'Bookings.html';" class="Bookings">Bookings</div>


<div onClick="window.location = 'Contact.html';" class="Contact">Contact Us</div>

 <div>
<img src="Assets/Feild1.jpg" class="Image1" style="vertical-align:central" />

<div class="Introduction">
Welcome to the Out and up website!
</div>

</div>
<body>
</body>
</html>

The CSS:

body,html {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}


body {
background-color:#CDCDCD;
overflow:scroll;
}
h1 {
color: navy;
margin-left: 20px;
}

.Head {
position: relative;
display: block;
}
.Head input {
padding-left: 20px;
}
.Head .Head-box {
width: 100%;
height:34px;
display:inline-block;
background-color:#ABABAB;
position:static;
top:-50px;
left:-8px;\
right:-100px;
margin-right:;
}

.Image1 {
width:100%;
height:auto;
position:relative;
margin-top:10px;
z-index:20;
left:-0.5px;
}



.Home {
width:60px;
height:30px;
background-color:transparent;
margin-left:92%;
margin-top:10px;
text-align:center;
padding-top:8px;
font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial,       sans-serif;
}

.Home:hover {
background-color:#E38600;
text-decoration:underline;
}



.Activities {
width:75px;
height:30px;
background-color:transparent;
margin-left:86%;
margin-top:-38px;
text-align:center;
padding-top:8px;
font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
z-index:10;
}

 .Activities:hover {
background-color:#E38600;
text-decoration:underline;
}
.Cafe {
width:50px;
height:30px;
background-color:transparent;
margin-left:82%;
margin-top:-38px;
text-align:center;
padding-top:8px;
font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.Cafe:hover {
background-color:#E38600;
text-decoration:underline;
}
.Bookings {
width:75px;
height:30px;
background-color:transparent;
margin-left:76%;
margin-top:-38px;
text-align:center;
padding-top:8px;
font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.Bookings:hover {
background-color:#E38600;
text-decoration:underline;
}

.Contact {
width:90px;
height:30px;
background-color:transparent;
margin-left:69%;
margin-top:-38px;
text-align:center;
padding-top:8px;
font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.Contact:hover {
background-color:#E38600;
text-decoration:underline;
}


.Introduction {
font-family:"Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:20px;
position:fixed;
margin-top:300px;
text-align:center;
width:100%;
display:block;
}
```

Comment: Without any code it's really hard :) plz show it with (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Hi! welcome to stackoverflow! First rule of stackoverflow is: post your code!

Comment: Sorry about that i'm new here. I edited the post with the code!

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is missing a normal structure: head tag wasn't closed, all the content is outside of body tag (which is empty). A valid html code is most important part of the page.
Secondly, regarding overflow issue - you probably need to add "bottom:0;" to .Introduction. Let us know if it helps.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry about the structure issues. I amvery new to HTML and CSS. This is my first time ever working on a website so i have had to experiment. i added the "bottom:0" to the .Introduction; this made the text i was using go to the bottom of the page, but this is not what i wanted. I wanted the text to be bellow what u can see on the screen, then scroll down to see this text, i am having troubles wiht the scrolling issue. Thanks for the help.